# crypto.computeSecret returns array of numbers instead of string

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Using Node's crypto, when I log results in Node, they're correct, but when I pass data into frontend (Angular) then log results, it gives an array.  The code is almost exactly the same.  Could someone tell me why it's giving me an array instead of a string?

Node:

```
app.get('/crypto', function(req, res) {

  var group = 'modp5';
  var aliceDH = crypto.getDiffieHellman(group);
  var bobDH = crypto.getDiffieHellman(group);
  aliceDH.generateKeys();
  bobDH.generateKeys();
  var publicKeys = aliceDH.getPublicKey('hex')
  console.log('pubkey: ', publicKeys)
  var bobSecret = bobDH.computeSecret(publicKeys, 'hex', 'hex')

  console.trace('Bob: ', bobSecret)

  res.send(publicKeys)
})
```

Log:

`pubkey:  72544df4dbc54e575814a1181eb42540d9220ce12ae47fac062ddd3c2f0c32a8793cfbf68099bebf0cef7aab52189c64e4830327d5bdc3d01f9a698ce86280c92ae9942a774f26b892635836b6bea5a413dc183c3cbfeca5e393e019e9940f47d9cc2d9657a03dc77a386c3892e40e1d23507a28ba285a43e90f817b76c8afd420bcedd0f808487133c17e215b0f5e0a5548a25558f8958a2b5e065c35c409d5db86680aab5499dbf8190677ef4225c93ef43e7b73b8ee69c941d16d292e879d`

`Bob:  6b078a9ce92b1f272930428cc0b6fc671eb377d936bbe37caffadd5d9d69755afd088236c73a3be8e86009b5de4dc7d32f4389129e332096e7064256469a700158a67cd1e1f59e25cdd135cb0c03bc904e8c5f571ed2c6662fbe8053396ec8dd5082787277644e592957546b43064d4fc9ea79def463e1092d0f54d62dad35a80e1896aeabadf7b44621090e52f45e422c7a0ffbfb9448b94c1c9afed08c4e97a27ba49115c2f87bf7b6547e8fa0b6011672d1ba4442e00bd4caac0f99f44428`

Angular:

```
$http.get('/crypto').then(function (res) {
            var key = res.data
            console.log(key)
            var group = 'modp5';

            var bobDH = crypto.getDiffieHellman(group);
            bobDH.generateKeys();

            var bobSecret = bobDH.computeSecret(key, 'hex', 'hex')
            console.log(bobSecret)
```

Log:

`72544df4dbc54e575814a1181eb42540d9220ce12ae47fac062ddd3c2f0c32a8793cfbf68099bebf0cef7aab52189c64e4830327d5bdc3d01f9a698ce86280c92ae9942a774f26b892635836b6bea5a413dc183c3cbfeca5e393e019e9940f47d9cc2d9657a03dc77a386c3892e40e1d23507a28ba285a43e90f817b76c8afd420bcedd0f808487133c17e215b0f5e0a5548a25558f8958a2b5e065c35c409d5db86680aab5499dbf8190677ef4225c93ef43e7b73b8ee69c941d16d292e879d`

`[174, 55, 88, 166, 67, 161, 206, 242, 245, 45, 4, 212, 164, 86, 84, 227, 65, 87, 190, 127, 204, 185, 217, 9, 66, 239, 242, 36, 211, 133, 195, 17, 208...]`

I'm guessing it has something to do with how I'm passing in the public key, but I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.  It appears fine, but I can't find a solution to this anywhere.  I found the exact same question here on SO, but it was not answered.

SIDE NOTE:  Node version is 0.12.16, and Angular version is 1.4.7

EDIT:  Doing more testing on this, and I find that using the EXACT SAME CODE from the Node side still gives me an array.  So not even doing an http call - actually using the same code still gives me an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue.  Although I told it to do everything in hex, it was actually giving the key as a buffer, so I added `.toString('hex')` and it finally converted to hex, and I was able to use it.